# iOS 4.3 Statusbar hidden shows white bar

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

I have slideshow developed for iOS 5, now im going to port it to iOS 4.3, when it show in full screen need to hide status bar in iOS 5 it is working properly but in iOS 4.3 status bar goes hidden but shows white stripe on top of view.the problem is how to hide statusbar in iOS 4.3 without white stripe.
This is the code use to hide status bar

Method 1

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Method 2

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

method 1 or method 2 didn't worked for ios4.3.

Comment: solved, before i was try to hide on viewWillAppear on full screen view  but before go to full screen hide status bar and then load full screen view properly hid the status bar when came back to normal view made status bar visible.

Answer (score 2):

write down the code in which view controller u want to hide the Status bar.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured this out yet, you'll also need to make sure that every involved view controller xib has the "Status Bar" set to none.